# Trigger Jenkins build on Butbucket PR

Tags: jenkins, build, bitbucket

How can I trigger builds from bitbucket on PRs and report back the results from jenkins. We have a Jenkins machine with no public IP address in Aws env, so the bitbucket pull request plugin isn't an option for us

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Bitbucket server within your own intranet and there is no way to access BB server from your Jenkins machine then I'm afraid there isn't much you can do. However, if you are running BB cloud or your BB server instance is accessible from the outside world, there is a solution.

You will need to first create a polling Job in Jenkins that runs every couple of minutes and calls the Bitbucket pull requests API. Get all the open PRs, which will be potential candidates for a build. Since you don't want to build a PR that has already been built, you will need to get the latest commit in a PR.

Then, check if that commit has been already built. If not, trigger a downstream job that builds the commit. Once the build finishes, make sure to update the build status for the commit saying that it has been built so that it doesn't get built again.

All the endpoints needed for this can be found in the documentation. Make sure you look in the cloud documentation if you are running BB cloud and server documentation if you are running BB server.

As you can see, it is a roundabout method, but it is your best option without using the plugin.